# SQL Developer Vendor Code 916

Tags: sql-server, oracle11g, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0wHj.jpg)

I am trying to access my sql server database to the oracle 11g using sql developer but when I open a database it says vendor code 916. See the picture. How to access?. Thanks

Comment: The error seems to indicate that you are trying to use Windows authentication and your SQL Server instance doesn't allow your Windows user to access that database.  No idea whether you should be using SQL Server authentication instead or whether you need to talk to your SQL Server DBA about granting that access.

Comment: @justinCave is there any other way to access my SQL Server using Oracle Sql Server?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Regardless of the client, you have to connect to SQL Server using a login that has access to the database that you want to access.  If you have such an account, you'd need to specify that when setting up the SQL Developer connection.  If you don't have that account, the SQL Server DBA would need to help you.  I have no idea whether you should be using Windows or SQL Server authentication.  Your DBA would if you don't.

Comment: @justincave Thanks I can finally access my database in sql developer now I use my username and password in sql server to log.in in sql developer and now its ok. Thanks for the time.